# Mysql update query - set to zero if out of range

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE users SET items=items-10000;
```

The problem is some users do not have 10000 items to deduct and I get the out of range error. How could the query be adjusted if the user does not have 10000 items, items will be set to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a [`CASE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
UPDATE users 
SET items=CASE 
  WHEN items-10000 < 0 
  THEN 0 
  ELSE items-10000 
END;
```

Or, [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
UPDATE users SET items=GREATEST(items-10000, 0);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `WHEN items > 10000` avoid double calculation ?

Comment: @Shimrod Do you mean `WHEN` or `WHERE`?

Comment: I think @Shimrod means `CASE WHEN items > 10000 THEN items-10000 ELSE 0 END` just to avoid calculating subtraction twice.  But IMHO that's likely to be micro-optimization.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.  (and of course it's micro-optimisation, but it can't harm, and requires only to change 1 place if number changes :-) )